# How to override base User in a Strongloop loopback scaffolded project?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop

Given a brand new project created with:

`$ slc lb project myapp`

How do I replace the '**user**' model in `models.json` with a '**customer**' model placed in the `./models` directory? Customers should have the login/logout etc. methods and 'users' should not exist as an API. Also, the customer model should not be dynamic. Let's pretend customer should have a schema as follows:

- name
- email
- password
- question
- answer
- phone
- verified
- dataCreated

I've been playing with this for a couple of days and my google-fu is letting me down. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the idiomatic way:

1. In `models.json`, rename `user` to `Customer`.
2. In `models/customer.js`, add custom methods to the model created via models.json:

   ```
   var app = require('../app');
   var Customer = app.models.Customer;

   Customer.myfn = function(cb) {
     // etc.
     cb();
   };
   ```

> Also, the customer model should not be dynamic. Let's pretend customer should have a schema as follows

Use `strict` to lock down the properties:

```
{
  "Customer": {
    "options": {
      "base": "User",
      "strict": true
    },
    "properties": {
      // define properties (schema)
    }
  }
}
```

See [Model definition reference](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Model+definition+reference) for more details.

**Update based on the comment below this answer**

It is possible to create your models code-first, see [customer.js](https://github.com/strongloop/sls-sample-app/blob/5864de5e29c20b942145d15d171b5115f33817a1/models/customer.js) in LoopBack's sample app that was built before `models.json` was introduced.

Here is what you should do in your code:

```
var app = require('../app');

var Customer = module.exports = loopback.createModel(
  'Customer',
  {
    name: 'string',
    // and all other more properties
  },
  {
    base: 'User',
    strict: true
  }
);

app.model(Customer);
```

That is basically the same code that is executed by `app.boot` for all entries in `models.json`. It should add the familiar REST routes to your application: `GET /customers`, `POST /customers/login`, `POST /customers/logout`, etc.

It is very difficult to help you without seeing your code that does not work and knowing what exactly do you mean by "not working".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works but ultimately this is not what I was looking for. I do not actually have anything against using models.json, however as a learning tool I wanted to try and divorce this Customer model completely from models.json. In my own initial attempts I placed customer.js & customer.json files in /models folder, which bought me nice CRUD rest endpoints, however they were lacking the /login sauce (I used a `base: user` property for customer).  Maybe I'm just asking my question wrong, or maybe the answer is; don't do that, the above method IS the way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get notified that this answer was updated. Yes, code-first was what I was after. I got there eventually and it basically matches exactly what you have above. Technically this is answered, but my Customer login doesn't work. When I post to `/customer/login` my result had id, ttl, and **userId**. Since the FK should be customerId I can't use the supplied accessToken. I think I'll mark complete and ask it as a new question. Thanks for your help.